# Python school quiz values will this code print

Tags: python, python-3.x

What values will this code print?  (use a comma separated list of values, like 1, 2, 3, 4)

```
for i range(2, 12, 4):
     print(i)
```

I don't understand what this question is asking I try and input

```
for i range(2, 12, 4):
     print(i)
```

but I keep getting a syntax error.

If anyone could give me an explanation about this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `for i in range.....` you forgot `in` between `i` and `range`

Comment: You're missing `in` between `i` and `range`.  The question is asking "what output will be produced by this code"?

Comment: 2, 2+4=6, 2+4+4=10

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the 'in' keyword.

```
for i in range(2, 12, 4):
     print(i)
```

Prints:

```
2
6
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "in" key word in your for loop. That way you can properly print out the numbers in range 2 to 11 with a spacing of 4

for i in range(2,12,4):
    print(i)

2
6
10